# Read data directly from folders for training in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

I am doing super resolution with resnet in keras and I have split my data into train and test (70-30) and from the test data 20% for validation .i am trying to read the data with datagen.flow_from_directory but its showing **0 images for 0 classes** .The main issue is i dont have classes. I only have high resolution images and low resolution images. The high resolution images goes to output and the low resolution images goes to input. How can i load the data without separating them in classess

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os

train_dir =  r'G:\\images\\train'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir)
```

Comment: How is the structure of your files under train directory?

Comment: Its just images no subfolders

Comment: If you have only one class like autoencoders and want to feed them as input, just set ``class_mode=input``. Don't forget that you have to set at least one subdirectory under the target.

Comment: @user123 https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#using_tfdata_for_finer_control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve **0 images for 0 classes**, notice that a common mistake is that the target folder you specify *has no subdirectory*. `ImageDataGenerator` splits data to classes, based on each subdirectory under the directory you specify as it's first argument. So, you should have at least one subdirectory under the target.

Furthermore, the generator should label them in order to feed them to your network. By default it uses **categorical** method as a 2D one-hot encoded labels. But if you want your labels in other ways, set `class_mode` argument. For example for autoencoders that inputs has no label, you should specify it as `class_mode=input`.

Base on the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx#flow_from_directory), `class_mode` should be one of these:

- `categorical` will be 2D one-hot encoded labels, (Default Mode)
- `binary` will be 1D binary labels,
- `sparse` will be 1D integer labels,
- `input` will be images identical to input images (mainly used to work with
  autoencoders).
- `None`, no labels are returned (the generator will only yield batches of image data, which is useful to use with `model.predict()`)